# Runtime error accessing a vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, runtime-error

In my C++ project, I have a class App, and a class Window. Class App has a parameter: `vector<Window*>* window;`.

In App's constructor, it is able to use and push_back a Window* onto this vector fine, but in my onMessage() method, which is called by the WndProc() (I'm using winapi), it gives me an runtime error when I try to use the vector. These are access errors.

What on earth could be going wrong? If you need any more info, just ask.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code.  The only that I can put a guess on is that its really a pointer to a vector, not a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the pointer to the vector is invalid or the pointers in the vector are invalid; probably the former in this case.  This happens in many situations, such as using pointers to local objects which have since been destroyed.

(Aside: Given that you included a semicolon for window, I bet this is a data member rather than a parameter.)

Instead of storing a vector pointer in App, store a vector itself.  Instead of storing pointers to Window objects, store the Window objects themself.

```
struct App {
  vector<Window> windows;
};
```

However, this requires Windows to be Copyable, and they probably aren't.  It also disallows storing objects of types derived from Window.  Instead, you can use a [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), which "owns" the pointed-to objects and will delete them when they are erased (such as when the ptr_vector is destroyed or cleared):

```
struct App {
  boost::ptr_vector<Window> windows;

  App() {
    // just an example
    windows.push_back(new Window());
    windows.push_back(new DerivedFromWindow());
  }
};
```

Comment: Turns out that I was accessing an object that didn't exist ( pointers... )